# Populate text box in Javascript by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to populate a text box on a form by clicking on form buttons.  Below is code I have so far - modified this code from a select box example -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function moveNumbers(){
            var no=document.getElementById("no");
            var txt=document.getElementById("result").value;
            txt=txt + option;
            document.getElementById("result").value=txt;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Select numbers:<br>
        <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers()"> 
        <input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers()"> 
        <input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers()"> 

        <input type="text" id="result" size="20">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("no")` needs an element to have the ID attribute set to "no". You don't have that.  Also, what's `option` in your function?

Comment: "no" is not the id, it's the name.  I think you want this:  document.getElementsByName("no")[0].value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few flaws here. It doesn't seem like `option` is defined. And you have no way to retrieve the button that was actually clicked.

What you can do is pass `this.value` to your onclick event handler. This passes the value of the button you push, and use that to append to your textbox value.

```
<script> function moveNumbers(num) {
    var txt=document.getElementById("result").value;
    txt=txt + num;
    document.getElementById("result").value=txt;
    }
</script>
Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="text" id="result" size="20">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cMN44/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the value of the button to be inserted into the text box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function moveNumbers(number){
            document.getElementById("result").value=number;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Select numbers:<br>
        <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)"> 
        <input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)"> 
        <input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)"> 

        <input type="text" id="result" size="20">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```