# Input text into text field on button press Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code at the moment it does not contain any javascript at the moment just HTML as im unsure how to go about doing this. The code below contains a keypad from 1 - 9 and 3 other buttons. For example if i press 1 Ix want it to input 1 into the field above the pinpad

[Visual Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq8AM.png)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center">
<h2>Pinpad</h2>
<hr>

<table style="display: inline">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            This is the Input field 
            <input type="password" readonly="yes" class="form-control" placeholder="PIN Number" style="text-align: center;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">1</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">2</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">3</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">4</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">5</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">6</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">7</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">8</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">9</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">0</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/feather0148/17dhf4ae/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate text box in Javascript by clicking on button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979569/populate-text-box-in-javascript-by-clicking-on-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You are trying to do something like this, so I have it a little bit elaborated for you:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2>Pinpad</h2>
    <hr>
    <table style="display: inline">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input id="input" type="text" readonly="yes" class="form-control" placeholder="PIN Number" style="text-align: center;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">1</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">2</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">3</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg clear"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">4</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">5</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">6</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg cancel"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">7</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">8</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg key">9</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg clear check"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg key">0</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container text-center error"></div>
```

**Js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //restrict the input
    var maxPin = 4;
    //add the chosen number
    $('.key').click(function(){
    $('.error').html('')
    if($('#input').val().length < maxPin){
        if ($('#input').val() == '') {
            $('#input').val($(this).html());
        }else{
            $('#input').val($('#input').val() + $(this).html())
        }
     }
  });
  //clear the iput field
  $('.clear').click(function(){
        $('.error').html('')
       $('#input').val('')
  })
  //remove the last inserted number
  $('.cancel').click(function(){
        $('.error').html('')
     $(input).val(
            function(index,value){
        return value.substr(0,value.length-1);
        })
  })
  //check
  $('.check').click(function(){

      alert('Do something with this')

  })
})
```

You can see the demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0he9jouw/

Comment: Wow that is amazing that is exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much

Comment: If this was useful for you please consider to up vote my answer. This is also important for other users seeking for the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

First, give every button an ID, then use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonId").click(function(){
        $("input:text").val("buttonNumber");
    });
});
```

hope this helps!
these can help too: [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_val_set)[another](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to assign the text field as well as the buttons unique id's ('field', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', ...)

Then you could structure your JavaScript like this:

```
function writeInField (e) {
    document.getElementById('field').value = document.getElementById('field').value+''+e.target.innerHTML;
}

document.getElementById('b1').addEventListener('click', writeInField, false);
document.getElementById('b2').addEventListener('click', writeInField, false);
document.getElementById('b3').addEventListener('click', writeInField, false);
```